# iPhone 7/ iOS 11.4.1: why does "Other" content consume all available storage?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory

I am user of iPhone 7 32GB on iOS 11.4.1 and I have this trouble since last month. Here is my memory usage :

​
[image: memory]

Other is "System" on iPhone

This freaks me out. I should restore my phone every 3-4 days, because when I restore it I got my 6 GB for System, but in 3-4 days it takes all available storage.
How may I fix it?
I already restored it with DFU, restored without backup and nothing.
Also I don't have officially Apple in my country.

Thanks

Comment: Hello Nikita Shchypylov, welcome to Ask Different. Other is "Settings, Siri voices, system data, and cached files" (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201656). I'd put the blame on cached files. The support article explains what they are: "Cached files are created when you stream or view content like music, videos, and photos. When you stream music or video, that content is stored as cached files on your iOS device so you can quickly access it again. Your iOS device automatically removes cached files and temporary files when your device needs more space." Would that make sense?

Comment: @jaume Hello James, thanks for reply. Not really, because I do use only Apple Music and it is no chance it takes 20 GB in 4 days! If it is, I am going for OnePlus 6 :)